# Dse graph indexing on vertex label using Java

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using Datastax **Dse grap** (5.x) **java driver** version 1.1.1 beta.

My use case is that **I can not allow more than one vertex to have same vertex label.**

For that I want to **create index on vertex label**.

I found this below code on  [Datastax official website](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createIndexes.html) `schema.vertexLabel('recipe').index('byRecipe').secondary().by('name').add()`

**But, this datastax tutorial lacks two things**

- How to create index on vertex label
- How to execute this using java

My question is **how to index Dse graph on Vertex label using java**?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this, you would execute the example as a graph statement.  It is typically recommended to create your schema outside of your application, traversal code base.

Answer (score 0):

If you are correct in stating that "you cannot allow more than one vertex to have the same vertex label", I think you need to reconsider your data model. A vertex label is intended to identify a group of vertices, with a vertex property distinguishing several vertices from one another.

If you created a vertex label "vtype" and a property "name" that identified each instance "vtype1, vtype2, etc.", then the index could be: schema.vertexLabel('vtype').index('byVType').secondary().by('name').add()